# Open webpage inside my app after button is clicked

Tags: android, android-webview

I have 5 buttons and i need to open different webpages after buttons is clicked. How to make it? 
my java code for webview activity:

```
  import android.webkit.WebView;

  import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


  public class WebView extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url)
    {
       v.loadUrl(url);
       return true;
    }
}
```

And xml:

```
<linearlayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="lv.shit.test.Sakums" >

<webview android:id="@+id/manswebview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    </webview>

</linearlayout>
```

What should I write on OnClick to open webpages in my webview?

Answer (score 0):

You can load different pages on your webView object on the click.
as

```
   webView.loadUrl("http://googlecom");
```

You can pas the url to the method loadUrl() under the webView object to preform the loading of different urls.

Answer (score 0):

Call this method inside the onClick listener:
    loadWebView(url);

```
public void loadWebView(String url){

    /*
     * Setting the options of my webView
     */
    mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.manswebview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

    mWebView.loadUrl(url);

    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
            super.onCloseWindow(window);

        }
    });

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


         @Override
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
             view.loadUrl(url);
             return false;
         }

        //when finish loading page
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        }          
    });
    //done loading now render the content
    this.setContentView(mWebView);

}
```